# Referencing column A and referenced column B in foreign key constraint are incompatibile

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, migration, nestjs

I have a problem with migration using sequelize + mySql + NestJS.
So I had to add new table with relation to another. New table migration looks like this:

```
import { DataType, Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript'

export async function up(queryInterface: QueryInterface) {
  await queryInterface.createTable('table_1', {
    id: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataType.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataType.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  })
}

export async function down(queryInterface: QueryInterface) {
  await queryInterface.dropTable('table_1')
}
```

And related table migration:

```
import { DataType } from 'sequelize-typescript'

export async function up(queryInterface: QueryInterface) {
  const transaction = await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction()

  try {
    await queryInterface.addColumn(
      'table_2',
      'column_1',
      {
        type: DataType.STRING,
      },
      { transaction }
    )
    await queryInterface.addConstraint('table_2', ['column_1'], {
      type: 'foreign key',
      onDelete: 'cascade',
      onUpdate: 'cascade',
      references: {
        table: 'table_1',
        field: 'id',
      },
      transaction,
    })

    await transaction.commit()
  } catch (err) {
    await transaction.rollback()
    throw err
  }
}

export async function down(queryInterface: QueryInterface) {
  const transaction = await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction()
  try {
    await queryInterface.removeConstraint('table_2', 'column_1', {
      transaction,
    })

    await queryInterface.removeColumn('table_2', 'column_1', {
      transaction,
    })
    await transaction.commit()
  } catch (err) {
    await transaction.rollback()
    throw err
  }
}
```

For some reason I get following error:

ERROR: Referencing column 'column_1' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'table_1_column_1_table_2_fk' are incompatible.

As you can see both id and column_1 has the same DataType.

Comment: I would check what the underlying properties of the two fields are. For example, different character set or collation can cause this error.

Comment: @Shadow you were right, I didn't pay attention to this, but setting charset and collate made things done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers, my problem was indeed as @Shadow mentioned charset and collate. I solved it by adding appropriate options to queryInterface.createTable in migration file as follows:

```
import { QueryInterface } from 'sequelize/types'
import { DataType, Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript'

export async function up(queryInterface: QueryInterface) {
  await queryInterface.createTable(
    'organization',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataType.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataType.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataType.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      organizationName: {
        type: DataType.STRING,
      },
      latestAmlResponse: {
        type: DataType.JSON,
      },
      countryCode: {
        type: DataType.ENUM('NO', 'SE', 'DK', 'FI'),
      },
    },
    { charset: 'utf8mb4', collate: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' }
  )
}

export async function down(queryInterface: QueryInterface) {
  await queryInterface.dropTable('organization')
}
```